# Plug in de controle de video no Moodle

Tags: web-service, aplicação-web, moodle, vídeo

Alguém sabe se existe algum modulo ou ferramenta que controla o acesso a vídeos no `Moodle`?

Eu estava pensando em criar alguma coisa do tipo, por exemplo: 
O aluno começou a assistir o vídeo numero 1 e parou de assistir aos `23:12` minutos de vídeo e saiu do sistema, quando ele entrasse novamente poderia ter a opção de continuar de onde ele parou, e com essa informação criar um web-service que pegasse esses dados e enviaria para um sistema esterno qualquer.

Alguém poderia me dar umas dicas de como fazer isso, e se é possível?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode desenvolver um plugin do tipo `modulo` para resolver essa problemática.
Os módulos no moodle ficam disponíveis no diretório `moodle/mod`. A sua ideia pode se basear em um conceito chamado `Pseudo stream` que o PHP nos oferece.

A lógica principal estaria no gerenciamento dos `stream em buffer`.

Comment: Léo, evite usar assinaturas. O SOPT tem um funcionamento diferente de um fórum, como você pode ver em [tour]. :)

Comment: Ok @DiegoF, não utilizarei assinaturas nos próximos.